# How to use pipe to sent parameters

Tags: linux, git, pipe, prettier

I'm failing to send the output of one command to be the parameters as the second command:

```
git diff --name-only HEAD | prettier --write
```

I want to send `prettier` all the modified files but I get the following error:

> No parser and no file path is given, couldn't infer a parser.

---

When I try it manually on one line from the output of the first command, it's working as expected:

```
 prettier --write --write path-of-the-file/file1.bla
```

---

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error could be because the command piped through, i.e. `prettier` does not read from the standard input but only when passed as positional arguments (`prettier <input-args>`). In general when the commands are piped, the standard output of the first command is connected to the standard input of the one following it.

Using `xargs` is exactly meant for that. Pipe the output received from the previous command and pass it along with ease. It should work on both the FreeBSD and the GNU based systems.

```
git diff --name-only HEAD | xargs -I {} prettier --write "{}"
```

Or if your shell is pretty new, and if its supports process substitution, you can run the command `prettier` for each output line of `git diff` as

```
while IFS= read -r op; do
    prettier --write "$op"
done< <(git diff --name-only HEAD)
```